# Eclipse / Aptana 3 : Launching wrong browser

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I just installed the Aptana Studio 3 plugin on my installation of Eclipse Juno, and attempted to use a portable install of Firefox to debug with, so that my general browsing install wouldn't get mucked up with a billion debugging features I don't need.

I set Eclipse's Window->Preferences->General->Web Browser to use this new portable install, but... it's still trying to launch my other install of Firefox. ("Please close down to complete installation" or whatever. I know the portable one isn't running.)

I just cannot get it to launch to the right browser. Firefox Portable is set up to allow multiple instances to be open, so I can get both my permanent install and my portable install to work at the same time, but Eclipse is trying to open the wrong installation.

I've tried restarting eclipse, closing Firefox , both internal/external web browser options on the web browser page, and even rebooting the whole computer. There are no other references to Firefox in the Eclipse settings that I can find.

... Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently that particular setting only affects browsing in the integrated browser, not running and debugging web applications.
The setting that needs to be modified for running/debugging is in the run/debug configurations. Why that doesn't by default automatically use the default browser set in the preferences page is beyond me.

In order to get Eclipse/Aptana to open the correct browser when debugging and running web applications, do this:
In the Project Manager, r-click on the project and go to **Run As** -> **Run Configurations...** and under 'Web Browser' in the left pane, either edit the default one or add a new run configuration. I just replaced the standard 'Firefox - Internal Server' entry.
In the Web Browser field, either type in the full path to the browser executable (in my case FirefoxPortable.exe), or click 'Browse' and browse to the executable.

That should do it.  and now it's doing what I would expect it to.